# Remove sequence of rows conditional on value in single cell in group-first position

Tags: r, dplyr

In this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sequ = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  G = c("A", "B", "*", "B", "A", "A", "*", "B")
)
```

I need to filter out rows grouped by `Sequ` **iff** the `Sequ`-*first* value is **`*`**. I can do it like so, but was wondering if there's a more direct and more elegant way in **`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  mutate(check = ifelse(first(G)=="*", 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(check != 1)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   Sequ [2]
   Sequ G     check
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 A         0
2     1 B         0
3     3 A         0
4     3 *         0
5     3 B         0
```

Comment: You could do `df %>%
    group_by(Sequ) %>%
    filter(first(G) != "*")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  filter(!first(G == "*"))
```

```
   Sequ G    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     3 A    
4     3 *    
5     3 B
```

Comment: The same solution was posted 8 hours before you posted yours

Comment: Upps. I just realized now. Thank you for drawing that to my attention. However beside the fact that it is the same answer (and I really did not recognized it) I am wondering if there is a difference in `filter(first(G) != "*")` vs. `filter(!first(G == "*"))`

Answer (score 2):

We can try the following base R code using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  !ave(G == "*", Sequ, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1))
)
```

which gives

```
  Sequ G
1    1 A
2    1 B
6    3 A
7    3 *
8    3 B
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` option with `duplicated`

```
subset(df, !Sequ %in% Sequ[G == "*" & !duplicated(Sequ)])
  Sequ G
1    1 A
2    1 B
6    3 A
7    3 *
8    3 B
```